# Difference between iCalendar v1 and v2

Tags: icalendar

Today I'm working on a project, which allows you to create E-Mail appointments as a simply file '.ics,.ifb,.iCal,.iFBf'. At first, I thought that the syntax between the file formats are different. Then I found RFC2445 (v1) from 1998 and RFC 5545 (v2). There are various iCalendar versions described.

Now to my real question: What are the differences between the versions?

I do not want to read a documentary with 300-page about it and compare it to find the differences. Maybe someone of you know the differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the table of contents on [RFC-5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), you'll see that [Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#appendix-A) of RFC-5545 calls out the differences between v1 and v2.

Most RFCs that extend a previous RFC have such a section.